# Syntax error on a piece of code which is accepted as an argument to str.join

Tags: python-3.x, string

Please clarify this behavior in python3:

```
>>> ''.join('<%s>%s</%s>' % (tag, content, tag) for tag, content in {'b': 'bold'}.items())
'<b>bold</b>'

>>> '<%s>%s</%s>' % (tag, content, tag) for tag, content in {'b': 'bold'}.items()
File "<stdin>", line 1
'<%s>%s</%s>' % (tag, content, tag) for tag, content in {'b': 'bold'}.items()
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join, its argument is supposed to be an iterable. If you look closely, the same argument provided to join in this example is giving an syntax error when inspected by itself.

I don't understand how this is supposed to work as an argument but can't be inspected as a value.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are passing a **generator expression** as an argument to the `join` method ([see this bit of documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and [this bit](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=generator%20comprehension#generator-expressions)).

When this kind of expression is used as an argument to a call, you can omit the parentheses.

If you surround the expression with parentheses in a Python interpreter, you will see something like this:

```
>>> ('<%s>%s</%s>' % (tag, content, tag) for tag, content in {'b': 'bold'}.items())
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f2ab9b044f8>
```

Note that you can confirm that you don't need the parentheses when it is part of an argument to a call like so:

```
>>> type('<%s>%s</%s>' % (tag, content, tag) for tag, content in {'b': 'bold'}.items())
<class 'generator'>
```

[From the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable):

> Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects [...]
>   Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed [...]
>   See also iterator, sequence, and generator.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I read about this once but now your answer reminded me :)